# Generating $S_n$ by taking subsets and compositions.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4553528/edit) a few days ago, but this question is really wholly different.

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group.  My question is, does there exist a subset $A$ of $S_n$ such that for every element $\sigma \in S_n$, $\sigma$ can be "constructed" by taking subsets of the elements in $A$ and permuting those subsets so that the corresponding composition equals $\sigma$?

That is, I want a subset $A \subset S_n$ such that any element of $S_n$ can be represented as a composition of some subset of elements of $A$ where each element of $A$ *appears at most once* in this composition.  If we take $|A|=m \geq n$, then we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m {m \choose i} i! \geq n!
$$
different possible subsets/permutations, so if $A$ is sufficiently large there should be enough "space" to "generate" $S_n$, but how can you construct such a set?  And *what would be the smallest possible $m$*?

*More formally*, let $A = \{\sigma_1,...,\sigma_m\}$ be a subset of $S_n$ with $m \geq n$.  Then does there exist an $A$ such that for every $\sigma \in S_n$, there is a $B \subseteq A$ with $B = \{\sigma_{a_1},...,\sigma_{a_k}\}$, $k \leq m$, and a permutation of the elements in $B$, call it $\sigma^* \in S_k$, so that if $\sigma^*(a_1,a_2,...,a_k) = (b_1,b_2,...,b_k)$ then
$$
\sigma_{b_1}\circ \sigma_{b_2} \circ \cdots \sigma_{b_k} = \sigma?
$$
And if such a set $A$ does exist, what is *the smallest possible $m$ for which such a set could be constructed?*

Comment: The set of transpositions works for $A$, so $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ is an upper bound for the minimal $m$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks.  Do we know if such a set $A$ exists however?

Comment: It is easy to verify that any permutation can be written as a product of distinct transpositions, so $A=\{x\in S_n | x \text{ is a transposition}\}$ is a valid choice for your set $A$. For example, $A=\{(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)\}$ works for $S_3$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis and there would be at most $n(n+1)/2$ such transpositions, so $|A|\leq n(n+1)/2$?

Comment: There are exactly $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ transpositions in $S_n$, but it could indeed be the case that there is a better choice of $A$ (i.e. one with fewer than $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ elements).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thank you!

Comment: I think there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ transpositions in  $S_n$. I really don't believe that this question is really wholly different from the previous one, but never mind, it's an interesting question!

Comment: I did some  quick computer checks for $n \le 9$, by just  choosing random subsets of $S_n$ of size $k$ and checking whether they satisfy your condition. For $k=3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ I quickly found suitable subsets of sizes $3,4,6,7,8,9,10$, respectively (and failed to find smaller such subsets). This suggests that the smallest possibly set $A$ has size not much larger than $n$, but I don't know how to go about trying to prove that.

Comment: @DerekHolt wonderful, thank you for the helpful comment.  May I ask what computer software you used to do this?

Comment: I used Magma, but it would be equally easy in GAP. I noticed a typo in previous comment, it should read "For $n=3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ I quickly ...".

Comment: Gah! I always make that mistake of confusing the $n$th triangular number with $\binom{n}{2}$. Derek is of course correct.